# Get command line arguments when running an Akka Microkernel?

Tags: scala, command-line, akka, microkernel

I have the [Akka microkernel](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/microkernel.html) below:

```
class ServiceKernel extends Bootable {

  val system = ActorSystem("service-kernel")

  def startup = {
    system.actorOf(Props(new Boot(false))) ! Start
  }

  def shutdown = {
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

Because the kernel extends `Bootable` and not `App`, how would I access command line arguments used when starting the kernel? For instance if I run the kernel using `start namespace.ServiceKernel -d rundevmode` or similar. Thanks!

### Additional Info

I thought it would be worth adding this information about the start up script in the microkernel. In `/bin/start` you notice the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

AKKA_HOME="$(cd "$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd -P)"/..; pwd)"
AKKA_CLASSPATH="$AKKA_HOME/config:$AKKA_HOME/lib/*"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2"

java $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$AKKA_CLASSPATH" -Dakka.home="$AKKA_HOME" akka.kernel.Main "$@"
```

Although om-nom-nom originally suggested `-D` options, it looks like it's in use and the main start up parameter is being passed to the `akka.kernel.Main` class (which in this case would be the `ServiceKernel` class above).

Comment: whoops my bad! :) fixed it LOL

Comment: Actually, if you're using -D options (which stands for *define*) you can just use `System.getProperty("rundevmode")` and check whether property was defined (passed in).

Comment: hmmm...that might do the trick. do properties require a value passed as well? and does it follow Scala `Option` or simply throw a java `null` if it can't find it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the minimal example:

```
object Foo extends App {
    val debugModeOn = System.getProperty("debugmode") != null
    val msg = if (debugModeOn) "in debug mode" else "not in debug mode"
    println(msg)
}

» scala Foo -Ddebugmode
in debug mode
» scala Foo            
not in debug mode
```

You can do extra check to overcome this issue:

```
» scala Foo -Ddebugmode=false
in debug mode
```

P.S. you might also want to use [Properties helper](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Properties%24), that contains bunch of methods like propOrNone, propOrElse, etc

Comment: Ah thanks for the quick answer. Here I was starting to write all this pattern matching. How silly and verbose of me ;)

Comment: You'll notice I just de-accepted this. sadly after further debugging i realized i was being fooled. If you look at the start script in `/bin`: `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$AKKA_CLASSPATH" -Dakka.home="$AKKA_HOME" akka.kernel.Main "$@"` meaning that `-D` has already been used :(

Comment: i might have a solution by supplying a custom script during build to accept more parameters. will update this when i know more.

Comment: haven't got something working yet. i'm probably going to fork the microkernel to allow for more `-D` parameters in a similar way it allows for JAVA_OPTS. nearly on a sharable solution.

Comment: Upgraded my SBT to `0.12.3` and looks like my version had a bug. It wasn't setting the main class. Now that I'm able to set my own main class (instead of Akka.main) I might be able to create custom classes representing dev/prod modes (or other params). Will update as it continues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the sh script that they give you an opportunity to provide JAVA_OPTS, and if not, they give you one that they pre-define.  I suppose you could just set JAVA_OPTS in a script that then calls this one, specifying a -D option for your custom args in the JAVA_OPTS.  That way you can be sure your custom args get passed in via the -D system property you specify. Hackish but I think it should work.  The beauty of -D is that you can supply as many as you want, so the fact that they are already using it for some of their own system properties should not matter.

Comment: Tried playing around with this solution, too, but the problem came down to the same issue om-nom-nom encountered with his: the default behavior of the Microkernel is to seek out Java classes using any parameters supplied. Therefore, anything will fail unless the start script is modified. Actively looking for a way to customize it during build without pain.

Comment: In looking at the source for the akka.kernal.Main class, I can see the issue now that you are talking about.  It treats any arg supplied as a class to boot, meaning if you supplied something like `my.BootClass -d testing` the `-d` and the `testing` would be expected to be FQN of `Bootable` classes and thus instantiated and booted up.  Hmmm.  Let me think a little more, see if there might be a way around this...

Comment: A workaround would be preferrable (though I wonder if achievable). It's really messy when we need to modify the build process. `sbt dist` is just so clean on its own LOL